# angular 6 component library using @import

Tags: angular, components, angular6

I am working with angular 6 to create my own component library.

I have used below steps to successfully create it:

1. ng generate library my-lib
2. Created few modules inside projects/my-lib/src/lib
3. exposed them under public_api.ts
4. imported them under my-lib.module.ts
5. Used ng-packagr to publish it

In my consuming app, I am also able to successfully utilize my component library.

I am using the below statement to import.

```
import { InputModule } from 'my-lib/lib/input'
```

what I want to do is, I want to consume my library components using

```
import { InputModule } from '@myOrg/input'
```

I could not find any documentation with ng-packagr. However, I could only find out under features section the following:

> Auto-discovers and bundles secondary entry points such as @my/foo,
>   @my/foo/testing, @my/foo/bar

Does some one know how to publish package with @ sign, the same way how we import angular features such as:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
```

Comment: Those are under node_modules with @name as the package's name, so you can configure package.json to grab a package with a similar name  (from a published repo or somewhere else).  Just create some dirs, for name-spacing, add index.ts's, and voila